# How to use sub queries with case when or coalesce functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, case, coalesce

I have a log table in which a new time stamp is added to the column ts as soon as a change is made, at the same time the time stamp of the last change is written to the column prevts.
What I would like to know is the newest update date of a certain field, if a certain field, like in this example the last name, was never updated and is the same since it was created, I would like to know the creation date.

| id | ts | prevts | operation | firstname | middlename | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-03T14 | 2023-01-17T08 | update | John | S | Doe |
| 1 | 2023-01-17T08 | 2022-10-20T03 | update | John | S | Doe |
| 1 | 2022-10-20T03 | 2022-10-06T14 | update | Johnny | S | Doe |
| 1 | 2022-10-06T14 |  | create | Johnny |  | Doe |

I am able to retrieve the update timestamps for single values like firstname and middle name (like in the code example below) but this does not work for lastname because this condition  `curr.firstname!=prev.firstname or prev.firstname is null` is not fulfilled. In such cases I would like to know the creation date.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT ON (curr.id)
curr.id,
prev.ts   AS curr_firstname_ts,
curr.prevts
FROM log_table curr
JOIN log_table prev 
  ON curr.prevts=prev.ts AND prev.id=curr.id
WHERE curr.firstname is not null
AND curr.firstname!='' 
AND (curr.firstname!=prev.firstname or prev.firstname is null)
ORDER BY curr.kolid, curr.prevts DESC NULLS LAST, prev.ts;
```

What I get as a result with this query is:

| id | curr_firstname_ts |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-17T08 |

What I would like to get is something like this:

| id | curr_firstname_ts | curr_middlename_ts | curr_lastname_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-17T08 | 2022-10-20T03 | 2022-10-06T14 |

Comment: you shpuld tale a look at recursive cte

Comment: The first two records in your table appear to have the same values in the 3 name columns, so there is no actual change - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from log1;
```

[Original data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xHRm.png)

| id | currts | prevts | ops | firstname | lastname | middlename |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 13:00:00 |  | create | Johnny | Doe |  |
| 1 | 2023-02-02 13:00:00 | 2023-02-01 13:00:00 | update | Johnny | Doe | S |
| 1 | 2023-02-03 13:00:00 | 2023-02-02 13:00:00 | update | John | Doe | S |
| 1 | 2023-02-04 13:00:00 | 2023-02-03 13:00:00 | update | John | Doe | S |
| 2 | 2023-02-01 13:00:00 |  | create | Mike | Smith | J |

(5 rows)

Run the query using window functions:

```
with a as (
    select id, currts,prevts, ops,
    firstname,lastname,middlename, 
    max(currts) over (partition by id) as maxts,
    min(currts) over (partition by id, firstname) as      minfirstnamets ,
    min(currts) over (partition by id, lastname) as minlastnamets ,
    min(currts) over (partition by id, middlename) as minmiddlenamets 
    from log1
)
select * from a where currts = maxts;
```

[Result data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z2MN.png)

| id | currts | prevts | ops | firstname | lastname | middlename |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 13:00:00 |  | create | Johnny | Doe |  |
| 1 | 2023-02-02 13:00:00 | 2023-02-01 13:00:00 | update | Johnny | Doe | S |
| 1 | 2023-02-03 13:00:00 | 2023-02-02 13:00:00 | update | John | Doe | S |
| 1 | 2023-02-04 13:00:00 | 2023-02-03 13:00:00 | update | John | Doe | S |
| 2 | 2023-02-01 13:00:00 |  | create | Mike | Smith | J |

Comment: This should work unless you have cases where one value is going from A to B to A.